# Why isn't this Left Join showing all data from table on left that doesn't match table on right? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have the following query which is supposed to be selecting all the articles from Articles_New which are either A) not in ArticlesInCategories_New or B) in it, but do not have the CategoryID = 7, 8, 9, 10, or 11.

**By removing the Category != lines, I've determined that the problem is (at the least) that Articles_New is not selecting everything from Articles_New that is not in ArticlesInCategories_New. I still don't really understand GroupBy, but I've based off of other questions, I've tried GroupBy Articles_New.ArticleID, and that didn't change anything.**

```
    SELECT 
       DISTINCT Articles_New.ArticleID, 
       DATE_FORMAT(Articles_New.PublicationDate, '%c/%e/%Y') AS ReleaseDate, 
       Articles_New.Title, 
       Articles_New.Type, 
       Articles_New.URL
     FROM 
       Articles_New
        LEFT JOIN ArticlesInCategories_New
            ON ArticlesInCategories_New.ArticleID = Articles_New.ArticleID
     WHERE 
       PublicationDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND
       PublicationDate <= CURDATE() AND
       Articles_New.Public = '1'
       AND ArticlesInCategories_New.CategoryID != '7'
       AND ArticlesInCategories_New.CategoryID != '8'
       AND ArticlesInCategories_New.CategoryID != '9'
       AND ArticlesInCategories_New.CategoryID != '10'
       AND ArticlesInCategories_New.CategoryID != '11' 
     ORDER BY 
       Articles_New.PublicationDate DESC,
       Articles_New.ArticleID DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all rows that are **either**:
A) not in ArticlesInCategories_New
B) in ArticlesInCategories_New, but do not have CategoryID = 7, 8, 9, 10, or 11.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Articles_New.ArticleID, 
   DATE_FORMAT(Articles_New.PublicationDate, '%c/%e/%Y') AS ReleaseDate, 
   Articles_New.Title, 
   Articles_New.Type, 
   Articles_New.URL
 FROM 
   Articles_New
    LEFT JOIN ArticlesInCategories_New
        ON ArticlesInCategories_New.ArticleID = Articles_New.ArticleID
 WHERE 
   (
     ArticlesInCategories_New.ArticleID IS NOT NULL AND
     PublicationDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND CURDATE()
     AND Articles_New.Public = '1'
     AND ArticlesInCategories_New.CategoryID NOT IN ('7','8','9','10','11')
   )
   OR 
   (
     ArticlesInCategories_New.ArticleID IS NULL
   )
 ORDER BY 
   Articles_New.PublicationDate DESC,
   Articles_New.ArticleID DESC
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I don't understand though why the `ArticlesInCategories_New.ArticleID IS NULL` is required. Isn't that the purpose of using a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @John, You have 2 conditions. The `is null` test tests for the first condition: it returns all rows for which there is **no match**. The other test is for the second condition. There I added `is not null` because you stated that there must be a match.

Comment: @John, the left join returns all rows in the left table (Articles_New) and data for those rows table match in the right table (ArticlesInCategories_New) {null for those that no not match}

Answer (score 1):

You describe two sets of articles that you want -- `all the articles from Articles_New` which satisfy one of the following:

- A) not in `ArticlesInCategories_New`
- B) in `ArticlesInCategories_New`, but do not have `CategoryID` = 7, 8, 9, 10, or 11.

You could simplify this complex query by finding these two sets separately, then combining them with a `UNION`.  This will allow you to test and debug each of the queries separately.

Comment: Without testing, it sounds like your answer would work. But, does writing two statements and combining them with a 'UNION' really simplify it? That seems just as complex

Comment: Opinions may vary -- but I think the important advantage is that you can `test and debug each of the queries separately`.